# How to improve speed of saving serial data to file in Python

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to implement a ramdump PC program that can get all of RAM data from a smart phone.
My code eventually works, but it is slow because of the file writing. How can I improve the file-writing speed in Python?

This is part of my code to receive serial data:

```
while recv_num < tot_num:
    remain_num = tot_num - recv_num
    for i in range(512):
        data = receive_qword()  # result=ser.read(size=8)
        f.write(data)
    recv_num = recv_num + 512
```

I already have a ramdump program written in C, and am working on converting this to Python. In my C code the function f_write(fil, ptr, size * count, &bwrite) works rapidly and seems to operate just like bulk steam.

Is there a mechanism in Python that is equivalent to this C mechanism?

Comment: How do you know that the program is slow because of file writing? Have you profiled it?

Comment: very good question. In Explorer, I Refreshed dump file by press the F5 key and found that the size of the file grew up in small piece compared to C program. That mean python program has more time of file writing than C. so I checked the f_write function in C. It could write data in file at once not at separate time

Comment: Both C's `fwrite` and Python's `file.write` buffer the output data. I would expect your slowness to come from reading in small chunks and creating a huge number of small strings.

Comment: Thanks. I Got it. You're right.